# Spring boot Connect with PostgreSql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, web-applications

The attached code are the error when connect the database with SpringBoot, the Problem is when application try to check the database, it told below error, SpringBoot with java version 11, and postgre version is with 11, so the version are all latest

Error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

Property files:

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Comment: Whuch version is your mysql connector driver?

Comment: Update your JDBC driver version in pom.xml

Comment: I have no pom.xml with grade managing dependency

Comment: I utilized PostgreSQL driver with version 9.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by updated the version of JDBC driver, since the JDBC driver should sync up with local PostgreSQL Version.